# Qualtrics - Language selection

Tags: qualtrics

I am using Qualtrics. I have a survey in 4 languages. I want to pre-select language say to German  & Dutch and don't want other languages to be displayed. One of the other languages is a primary language so unfortunately I can't delete it. Have a nice day.

Comment: Can you please add some code how you added Qualtrics in your application? Did you tried anything from Qualitrics help/wiki?

Answer (score 2):

You can add CSS to hide the language selector. Under Look&Feel/Advanced/Add Custom CSS, add the following:

```
.LanguageSelectorContainer {display:none;}
```

Then use a contact list (panel) or url parameter to pre-select the language.